# Pick up numbers from a series every time a positive appears

Tags: r

I would like to create a new series of numbers picking up numbers every time a positive one appears and leaving numbers every time a negative one appears. For example :

```
f <- c(1,34,56,-3,-26,-4,-1,17,28,-6,-9,-3,12,-13,15,18)
```

Into:

```
g = 34  56  -3 28  -6  -13  18

#[+1](positive:start) 34  56  -3 (negative:stop) 
#[-26,-4,-1, +17](positive:start) 28 -6 (negative:stop)etc...
```

I hope to be clear.

I would like also to do another different thing: every time i find a negative number the next numbers will become negative until a positive appear. For example:

From

```
f <- c(1,34,56,-3,-26,-4,-1,17,28,-6,-9,-3,12,-13,15,18)
```

Into

```
h = 34  56  -3 (negative: change sign)  26  4  1  -17(was positive: back to normal sign) 28 -6  etc...
```

Any help?

Comment: Following @Psidom's "lead", you could do `f[data.table::shift(f > 0, fill = 0)]` as well.

Answer (score 7):

```
library(dplyr)
f[lag(f > 0)][-1]
[1]  34  56  -3  28  -6 -13  18
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks !!

Comment: Could also do `f[lag(f > 0, default = FALSE)]` and not have to remove the first element from the result.